# On the Codechef aug long challenge, AUG21C >CHFINVNT, this is the code I wrote, but the submit doesn't work. Its showing RE(NZEC) error

Tags: java, input

On the Codechef August long challenge, AUG21C  > CHFINVNT, this is the code that I wrote, but the submit doesn't work. It's showing RE(NZEC) error.
The output still works.... but it won't submit. Please help.

```
/* package codechef; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Codechef
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        try {
        int T = scr.nextInt();
        
    
        
        while(T-- > 0)
        {
            int N = scr.nextInt();
            int p = scr.nextInt();
            int K = scr.nextInt();
            
            
            int[] A = new int[N];
            
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            {
                A[i%K]++;
            }
            
            int sum=0;
            
            for(int i=0; i<p%K; i++)
            {
                sum+=A[i];
            }
            
            int add = (p - (p%K)) / K;
            add++;
            
            sum = sum + add;
            
            System.out.println(sum);
             
            
            
           
        }
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "RE(NZEC) error"?

Comment: no such element error

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you have a flaw in your code. `NZEC` means non-zero exit code. Your code probably triggered an uncaught exception. Although you have a broad `catch` statement, there are exceptions outside of your catch clause.

In the question statement, `N` can be as large as 10^9.

If that happens, `int[] A = new int[N];` tries to allocate that memory. That is over the memory constraints. Probably that is causing the problem. Even if you could allocate that memory, you would hit the time limits: even counting to 10^9 shall fail on CodeChef.

Not directly related to the question, but I want to comment on your code from the perspective of software engineering and competitive coding best practices.

- Having a broad catch block will hide any exceptions you may have. Even if you get an index-out-of-bounds exception, you shall not be able to see that in your trials. You may avoid catching broad exceptions.
- Your code does not have a proper indentation. That makes reading & debugging cumbersome. Especially in competitive programming, speed is important. So, a proper indentation is critical in that regard. You may just use an IDE to format the code.
- Your Java code does not follow the general conventions of Java. One of the rules is "local variables start with a lowercase". The local variables `A` and `N` violate that rule.
- The code you submitted contains many empty lines. While submitting your code to StackOverflow, removing unnecessary lines shall ease the reading and increase the probability of getting a good answer.